# Causal networks with correlated variables

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network

I've been reading about Bayesian networks and one of the central assumptions these networks require is conditional independence. However, the problems I'm working on involve variables that are often correlated with each other and conditional independence assumptions do not hold.

I looked into Weighted Correlation Network Analysis, also known as Weighted Gene Co-Expression Analysis, however these tools seem more akin to clustering and do not actually strive to model causal relationships.

I also found this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/srep25156
Bae, H., Monti, S., Montano, M. et al. Learning Bayesian Networks from Correlated Data. Sci Rep 6, 25156 (2016). https://doi.org/10.1038/srep25156.

These authors I think attempt to use the concept of linear mixed models to regain some of the conditional independence assumptions while allowing correlation to be present in the model.

I think this is possibly similar to what I'm looking for, however I've not found anyone else doing work like this.

What statistical tools exist for trying to do probabilistic graphical models without conditional independence assumptions and also work for relatively low sample sizes (50-200 observations)?

Comment: Did you try Markov random field?

Comment: @JYY That was going to be my next approach. However, doesn't it still require the similar assumptions as a Bayesian network as far as conditional independence? I thought they relied heavily on conditional independence

Comment: Conditional independence does exist in Markov random field, but the relationships between variables in MRF are "bidirectional". You can read Chapter 4 in the book "Probabilistic Graphical Model, Principles and Techniques" by Koller and Friedman, it gives a nice introduction.